# Laravel 7 whereIn query only returns the first index

Tags: laravel

I have an laravel app where i'm trying to display all posts from all users on a main index page. However i am having trouble trying to query all the posts from all users. the code below only gets all the posts from the first user.

Here is the query

```
//grab all users from the database and store it in the users variable
$users = User::all();
//grab all posts from all users. list by most recent in descending order store in recentPosts variable
$recentPosts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users)->paginate(32);
//return the view with the varibles
return view('index', compact('recentPosts'));
```

Here is `dd($users);`

[image]

Here is `dd($recentPosts);`

[image]

here is my database with 2 posts from 2 separate users
[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$users` is a collection, not an array. You need to get array to use `whereIn`. Maybe you can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) method:

```
$recentPosts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $users->pluck('id'))->paginate(32);
```

Comment: @OMR Yes you correct, but it can be used in whereIn. because it's Illuminate\Support\Collection that return value like array.

Answer (score 0):

fix this `whereIn()` req array so you can use this ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

and `pluck()` to get all `userId`  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

```php
$userIds = User::all()->pluck('id')->toArray();
//grab all posts from all users. list by most recent in descending order store in recentPosts variable
$recentPosts = Post::whereIn('user_id', $userIds)->paginate(32);
```